# Runtime of model may vary greatly on different android devices when using TensorFlow-Lite because of different computing capacity

Tags: android, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When using TFLite to run NN model on Android devices, There are too many Android devices, different devices have different computing performance. So it's hard to use a single model to cover all devices.

One solution is to use models with different FLOPs for different devices based on the `computing capacity` of the device.

However, there is no API in TFLite to get the `computing capacity`. So I'm curious how to deal with the situation.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no idea about TensorFlow. That said, perhaps it is helpful for other SO users to explain why you can change the used model?
And perhaps from a UX view you can add a selection similar to graphics options in video games (Low, Medium, High, Ultra). That way the end user can select the model himself. (If you have a GUI at all. :) )

Comment: @gillesB 1. how to change the model: you could download the model from remote server, or you could package multiple models in your SO if the size is right. 2. Good advice, but it's not suitable for our cases. By the way, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no solid story for this. One thing you might consider is to run floating point models on powerful devices, but quantized models (with accuracy hit) on less performant ones. However, this is super manual since as you said there's no API in tflite to get computing power now.